# UIToolbar doesn't rotate correctly when at the top of the screen

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, uitoolbar

My UIToolbar doesn't rotate correctly when it's placed at the top of the screen. When rotated, it rotates out of the screen. However, when I place it at the bottom of the screen, it works fine. Does anyone else have a solution to this problem? The only reason I'm bothering with this is because I'm making a web browser and usually the address bar is at the top of the screen, but you're limited to only two objects in a UINavigationBar (back button, text field, forward, refresh, etc). Any ideas? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Is it at y=0? Did you setAutoResizingMask to UIViewAutoResizingMaskFlexibleBottomMargin?

Comment: It works when placed at the bottom of the screen. When moved to the top, it doesn't work. Try it. I've also tried resizing it and moving it using its frame property, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Are you using a nib, or are you doing this programatically?

Comment: I'm putting it directly in the XIB. The problem has been resolved below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Who says you are limited to only two objects in the `UINavigationBar`? You can set the `leftBarButtonItem` & `rightBarButtonItem` properties to any custom view. If you need more buttons, you can create a UIBarButtonItem with a `UIToolbar` as a custom view, and add as many buttons to the `UIToolbar` as you want.